# How to prevent method from being executed concurrently by different threads within the same class instance

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Say I have two threads, both started from a given class instance, A. The threads have to execute a method from the same instance, but one at a time. I tried making the method synchronized but apparently it applies when there are different instances trying to call the method (from what I understood; pardon me if I'm wrong).

So how do I go about accomplishing this, preferably in a standard or recommended manner?

EDIT: Here's the relevant code:

```
public class A {
.
.
.
  public void method1(){

    ExecutorService threadObject = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            threadObject.execute(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while (someCondition) {
                          //Here's one invocation
                          someObject = readObject();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {}
                }
            });

    //Here's the other invocation
    while(someCondition){
      someObject = readObject();
    }
  }

  //Here's the synchronized method
  private synchronized SomeClass readObject() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
          return (SomeClass) incomingResponses.readObject();
  }

  //Main method to instantiate the class
  public static void main(String ... args) {
    A = new A();
    A.method1();
  }
}
```

I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please post your synchronized code.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin I've added the relevant code.

Comment: I cannot see in your code 2 threads working on the same instance of A. I see only 1 thread and no instances of A.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov, Agreed, the example is incomplete, but there _are_ two threads: There's the main thread, and there's the thread that the `threadObject` executor creates.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Sorry, should've reviewed the snippets more thoroughly; hopefully the code is now making much more sense

Comment: @SolomonSlow I've made further edits to better clarify the problem (I hope)

Comment: " it applies when there are different instances trying to call the method " - please say it in other words, I cannot understand what do you mean.

Answer (score 1):

`synchronized` methods are a shortcut.  IMO, you should learn to do it the long way before you start using the shortcut:

If you have this:

```
class A {
    synchronized SomeType myMethod(...) {
        doSomeStuff(...);
        ...
        return someThing;
    }
}
```

That is a shortcut for writing a method declaration with a top-level [synchronized *statement*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html):

```
class A {
    SomeType myMethod(...) {
        synchronized (this) {
            doSomeStuff(...);
            ...
            return someThing;
        }
    }
}
```

IMO, you should learn how to use synchronized statements first, and then only use synchronized methods when you have a better understanding of how synchronized statements work.

Comment: Will surely look more into that. What's the advantage of using synchronized statements over the synchronized methods though?

Comment: There's no advantage of _using_ synchronized statements, but your original question shows that you do not fully understand Java's intrinsic synchronization.  I'm saying that you should _understand_ `synchronized` statements first, because then, `synchronized` instance methods and `synchronized` class methods are trivially easy to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is wrong. Quoting the relevant example from [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html):

> - First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing
>     a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke
>     synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution)
>     until the first thread is done with the object.
> - Second, when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent
>     invocation of a synchronized method for the same object. This
>     guarantees that changes to the state of the object are visible to all
>     threads.

So, `synchrinzed` keyword applied on method will not allow concurrent invocations of the method on a particular object instance.

Comment: I've added the relevant code for more clarification